# colors with headers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, markdown

I have some custom color and I'd like the headers of `fancyhdr` to be colored differently.

How do you make the different headers `\fancyhead[L]`, `\fancyhead[R]`, `\fancyhead[C]` have different colorboxes and font colors? How do you make `\fancyhead[R]` have a different font size?

Thank you.

Here is what I currently have:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
classoption: landscape
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: false
    dev: pdf
    keep_tex: false
    toc: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{etoolbox}
- \usepackage{color}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{7, 252, 3}
- \definecolor{col2}{RGB}{7, 200, 3}
- \fancyhead[L]{% 
    \colorbox{col1}\color{blue}{left}%
    }
- \fancyhead[R]{% 
    \colorbox{col2}\color{red}\fontsize{12?}{right}%
    }
- \fancyhead[C]{  %  \colorbox{col2}\color{white}\nouppercase{\leftmark} %   }
- \let\oldheadrule\headrule
- \renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{col2}\oldheadrule}
---




```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\newpage

# page 3

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressured, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\colorbox{<colour>}{<stuff>}` takes two arguments. The first is the `<colour>`, while the second is the `<stuff>` contained within the box. Using

  ```
  - \fancyhead[L]{% 
      \colorbox{col1}\color{blue}{left}%
    }
  ```

  mistakenly puts `\color` as the second argument to `\colorbox`, which doesn't make sense. You need to use something like

  ```
  - \fancyhead[L]{\colorbox{col1}{\color{blue}left}}
  ```

  Note also the use of a single line rather than breaking a line; writing header content (via `header-includes`) in Markdown doesn't translate in the same way you'd think.
- To change the font size, use `\fontsize{<size>}{<baseline skip>}\selectfont`. In your case, something like `\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont` would work.

You may get some warning about the header height being too small. For that, add

```
- \setlength{\headheigh}{<height>}
```

to match your needs (where `<height>` is at least as large as the suggested height).

Comment: Thank you. What would be the order for the font size and colorbox and color:  - \fancyhead[C]{\colorbox{col2}{\color{col1}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\nouppercase{\leftmark}} that gives an error \begin{document}

Comment: @user3022875: That order and bracketing seems fine. Do you have all the other header elements in a single line?

Comment: Yes it is all in a single line.

Comment: @user3022875: You need a closing brace.